# For how long the test data generated jobs can be retained in HCL OneTest Data? Can a user configure this period for jobs?

Tags: jobs, configure, data-generation, retention

Can a user configure the retention period for jobs in HCL OneTest Data? If yes, then how can a user configure the retention period of jobs and the generated files?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can configure the retention period for jobs in HCL OneTest Data. By default, the period to retain the jobs is 5 days. You can configure the value of the retention period in the HCL OneTest Data app pod.
You can refer to the following document to learn how to configure the retention period:
https://help.hcltechsw.com/onetest/hclonetestserver/10.1.2/com.hcl.test.otd.help.doc/topics/t_help_configure_job_clearance.html